# Replace 1s with 0s in numpy array depending on which rows the 1s are located in

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix M with 60,000 rows and 10,000 columns. Each element is either a 0 or 1. For each column, I would like to keep only the first '1' in each row between row x and y; remaining 1s must be replaced with 0. Also note that ranges [x1:y1] and [x2:y2] will never overlap, ie. it will never be that x2 < y1. Also, the ranges yi-xi are not all necessarily the same length for all ranges i.

The issue that makes this problem more tricky is that y depends on which row the 1 is located. For example, let's consider the first column of the matrix M. Suppose there is a 1 on `rows=[3,7,9,10,25]`. You can then find the y for each row by indexing in `y_bound`. If `y_bound[3]=10` then, you would remove the '1's in column one and replace them with '0' between rows 4 and 9 inclusive. Note that x=3+1=4 and y=10-1=9. You now move on to the next *remaining* '1', which would be in row 10 as defined by `rows=[3,7,9,10,25]` (since we do not look at 7 and 9) since those 1s have now been removed. Suppose `y_bound[10]=23`, then you would replace all '1's in between 11 and 22 inclusive with '0' (which happened to be none in this case).

This has to be done for all columns in the matrix. The good news is that `y_bound` depends only on which row a 1 is located and not in which column it is. Here is a reproducible example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
import numpy as np

M = np.random.randint(2, size=(20,10)) # random matrix of 0s and 1s
y_bound = np.array([[4,6,7,8,9,7,11,12,14,16,19,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20]]).T # length = 20

# Replace 1s with 0s
for column_number, col in enumerate(M.transpose()):
    rows_with_ones = np.argwhere(col==1)
    
    previous_y = 0
    
    for row in rows_with_ones:
        x = int(row) # convert array to integer
        
        if x >= previous_y:
            y = int(y_bound[x]) # index into this array
            previous_y = y
            
            # Replace 1s between the current row and the row just before that given by y_bound in the line above
            M[x+1:y,column_number] = np.where(M[x+1:y,column_number] == 1,0,0)
```

Any help is much appreciated! It is worth noting that I am running this on a GPU in Google Colab (using Cupy -- the GPU equivalent of numpy). I would ideally like an implementation that does not take too long to run (hopefully without for loops) as this process needs to be repeated 10,000 times.

Comment: Any manipulations on a matrix with 600,000,000 elements is going to take a fair amount of time...

Comment: Can you give a small and representative example?

Comment: That's true @TimRoberts, that's why I'd like something *relatively* quick compared to something like a for loop for example.

Comment: I have now added an example with code @NilsWerner

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem, but it's just brute force.  You can see my attempt at using `np.where` to return the list of 1s in the column.  It does do that, but I don't think it is more efficient.  np still has to troll through the whole column, and then you have the issue of handling rows already cleared.

```
import numpy as np

M = np.random.randint(2, size=(20,10)) # random matrix of 0s and 1s
y_bound = [4,6,7,8,9,7,11,12,14,16,19,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20]

print(M)
print()

#for col in range(x.shape[0]):
#    ones = np.where( x[:,col] )
#    print( col, ones )

def mine(x):
    for col in range(x.shape[1]):
        for row in range(x.shape[0]):
            if x[row,col]:
                print( col, [row+1,y_bound[row]])
                x[row+1:y_bound[row],col] = 0


# Replace 1s with 0s
def his(M):
    for column_number, col in enumerate(M.transpose()):
        rows_with_ones = np.argwhere(col==1)
        
        previous_y = 0
        
        for row in rows_with_ones:
            x = row[0]
            
            if x >= previous_y:
                y = int(y_bound[x]) # index into this array
                previous_y = y
                
                # Replace 1s between the current row and the row just before that given by y_bound in the line above
                print( column_number, x+1, y )
                M[x+1:y,column_number] = np.where(M[x+1:y,column_number] == 1,0,0)

m = M.copy()
mine(m)
print(m)
print()
m = M.copy()
his(m)
print(m)
```

Output:

```
[[1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0]
 [1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1]
 [1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]]

[[1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]

[[1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

Comment: Based on your output it doesn't seem to do exactly what I'm looking for. I nevertheless appreciate your attempt :) I have attached code showing what I would like the function to do. Then again, optimally I would not do it with brute force.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo that didn't limit the erasure to one column.  I'll fix it.

Comment: For the record, my version is about 7 times faster than yours.  1000 cycles on mine is 67ms, 1000 cycles with yours is 476ms.

Comment: Interpolating, that means I could do your 600M elements in about 4 minutes.

Comment: Wow! Not bad at all! A massive improvement from my version... However, as I need to run this 10,000 times it seems it will still take too long. I fear that it may not be possible to provide a solution that can do this for all columns at once without having to loop through...